# Cannot disable Query store due to QUERY STORE ASYNC LOAD

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-store

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-GDR) (KB4505220) - 13.0.5101.9 (X64).

One of our databases seem to have a run away Query Store with over 90 gb stored. I want to disable QS, but cannot do so because disable queries get blocked.

After a server reboot, the database got stuck in *something* related to query store loading, so every query you ran was blocking in that db due to QDS_LOADDB.

`ALTER DATABASE someDb SET QUERY_STORE = OFF` and `ALTER DATABASE someDb SET QUERY_STORE CLEAR ALL` are likewise stuck against some SQL Server internal-process which was unkillable.

After i enabled trace flags 7745 + 7752, i could at least move the query store loading into async load, which doesn't block regular queries. But `ALTER DATABASE someDb SET QUERY_STORE = OFF` still blocks due to `QUERY STORE ASYNC LOAD` command.

The question, how do i disable Query Store on such a run away database? I have a bad feeling that the "QUERY STORE ASYNC LOAD" will never finish

Answer (score 2):

Did you try ?

```
ALTER DATABASE [dbname] SET QUERY_STORE = OFF (FORCED)
```

Comment: Yeah, it's not available in my server version (incorrect syntax near FORCED). But if everything fails, i might be able to patch it to the latest SP

Comment: yeah I'd definitely think of patching, you have quite a few security patches missing.
this syntax came in CU14 of SP2
https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/erin/how-to-turn-off-query-store-in-an-emergency/

In the link below you can see all of the builds (including the remote code execution fixes ;-) )

https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/#sql2016x